# How to apply the .toggle() only in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

How to apply the .toggle() only the clicked DIV.
My current code applies to all toggle div.
The code switch between the content from `<div class="toggled">`

**I need to do it in version 1.4**

Anyone can help me?

This my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="card.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#toggle').click("click", function() {
            $('.toggled').toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>


<div class="card">

    <div class="toggled">
    <h3>FRONT 1</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="toggled" style="display:none;">
    <h3>BACK 1</h3>
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="toggle">Switch Text Toggle</a><br/>

</div>


<div class="card">

    <div class="toggled">
    <h3>FRONT 2</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="toggled" style="display:none;">
    <h3>BACK 2</h3>
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="toggle">Switch Text Toggle</a><br/>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change the ID of the anchors to a class, as ID's are unique.

Then you'd do:

```
$(function() {
    $('.toggle').on("click", function() {
        $(this).siblings('.toggled').toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Where you find the siblings of the clicked anchor with the class `.toggled`, and toggle those. You also need a document.ready function, and the event handler has some  typos.

And use a newer version of jQuery, 1.4 is outdated.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Ye9aw/1/)

Comment: @SpecTrum - All you really have to do for this to work in 1.4 is replace on() with a regular click() handler, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Ye9aw/2/) !

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$('.toggled').toggle();` with `$(this).toggle();`. You're currently requesting all `.toggle` containers be toggled, not the one that is the focus of the event.

Comment: how this change makes "<a href="#" id="toggle">Switch Text Toggle</a><br/>" disappear instead the switch between the "<div class="toggled">" DIVs. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.card #toggle').click(function() {
            $('.toggled').toggle();
            return false;
        });
```